# How do I restore a file tree in windows visible after data recovery?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

To be brief..

New terabyte HD gets messed up after a few weeks due to motherboard incompatibility.

After a successful Easeus partition wizard scan, Easeus can see all my old file tree / folders and files. But it wants to physically recover the files to another location (but i don't have the space other than on that drive - which of course data recovery doesn't like to do!)

If Easeus can see the file system then surely there is a way to simply restore the file system / tree on that drive to Windows satisfaction?

My question: How do i restore the file tree that Easeus (but  not windows) can happily see so that windows will also see it and the HD's file system is corrected back to how it was?

PS In Windows 7 the drive just reports back as begin formatted

Thanks
Melissa

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is, if you write to the same drive that you're recovering from you may over-write the very data you're trying to recover.  The more data you're trying to recover the higher the probability you'll do that.

The only safe thing to do is to recover the data to another location (and optionally then move it back).  I'd borrow (or buy) an external drive for the task.  The bonus of buying one is that then you'll have somewhere to back your data up to so that if/when this happens again you don't find yourself with the same problem.